# Laravel migration won't reference second foreign key

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying to reference the id of a product on two tables (a categories and a brands table).

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('products', function($table)
        {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
                $table->string('title');
                $table->text('description');
                $table->decimal('price', 6, 2);
                $table->boolean('availability')->default(1);
                $table->string('image');
                $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table('products', function($table){
                $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
                $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');
        });
}
```

But I get the following errors:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
: alter table `products` add constraint products_brand_id_foreign foreign k
ey (`brand_id`) references `brands` (`id`))


[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Which is the correct way to do this?

**Update**

Migration public function up for the brands table

```
public function up()
{
        Schema::create('brands', function($table){
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('name');
                $table->timestamps();
        });
}
```

**Solution**

Finally, the error was on the naming of the migration. Due to the fact that brands table was the most recent table I had to changed its name from: `2014_12_12_164325_create_brands_table` to this `2014_10_12_164325_create_brands_table` and the tables were migrated successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks ok to me. Furthermore, since it only complains about the second part, the categories foreign key must've worked. I would think the brands table doesn't exist or there is something wrong there. Does the table exist and does it have a primary key "id"?

I also use

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
```

at the beginning, because MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys as of now. I don't think it should be an issue in the above case, but perhaps still advisable, if you want to do foreign key restrictions on the DB level.

Comment: I've added InnoDB as well but this didn't changed anything. And yes the categories foreign key works. A table named brands also exists. I am including its public function up in my question above.

Comment: Although, the brands table is the most recent table created. Is that creating a problem on the sequence that laravel migrates the files?

Comment: And it does! I've changed the migration's name and everything were migrated successfully!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer! Yes, the sequence definitely has a big impact. I also have had problems with the correct sequence, because wrong sequencing can also cause trouble when you want to do a php artisan migrate:reset or php artisan migrate:refresh (e.g. it won't let you delete stuff when there are still dependencies).